# Script time limit for Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I need to change some formulas at the same cells at an specific sheet (LISTAFINAL) present in a great number of spreadsheets, these one located at the same folder. But it stops at Google script time limit of 6 minutes, making changes only in 9 spreadsheets, and comes the message: `Erro - Exceeded maximum execution time`.

1. My goals:

I would like to know if there's any way to or speed up this process or make changes in a bigger number of spreadsheets or both. Here is the code:

```
function validacao(){
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER ID");
  var x = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  while (x.hasNext()) {
    SpreadsheetApp.open(x.next()).getSheets().forEach(sheet => {
      sheet.getRange('LISTAFINAL!F5:F15').activate();
      sheet.getRange('LISTAFINAL!F5').setValue('=ALUNO1!$F$167');
      sheet.getRange('LISTAFINAL!F6').setValue('=ALUNO2!$F$167');
      sheet.getRange('LISTAFINAL!F7').setValue('=ALUNO3!$F$167');
      sheet.getRange('LISTAFINAL!F8').setValue('=ALUNO4!$F$167');
      sheet.getRange('LISTAFINAL!F9').setValue('=ALUNO5!$F$167');
      sheet.getRange('LISTAFINAL!F10').setValue('=ALUNO6!$F$167');
      sheet.getRange('LISTAFINAL!F11').setValue('=ALUNO7!$F$167');
      sheet.getRange('LISTAFINAL!F12').setValue('=ALUNO8!$F$167');
      sheet.getRange('LISTAFINAL!F13').setValue('=ALUNO9!$F$167');
      sheet.getRange('LISTAFINAL!F14').setValue('=ALUNO10!$F$167');
      sheet.getRange('LISTAFINAL!F15').setValue('=ALUNO11!$F$167');
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation:

- You iterate over all sheets for every spreadsheet file. Your goal is to just get a single sheet and put the formulas in specific cells. Therefore, you can get rid of the `forEach` loop.
- It is a [best practice](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) to work with arrays instead of iteratively using multiple google apps script functions.
- For example, in your code you are using `getRange` and `setValue` 11 times. If you store the formula values in an array you will be able to store them by using only a single `getRange` and `setValues`.

### Solution:

```
function validacao(){
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER ID");
  const x = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  const formulas = Array(11).fill().map((_, i) => [`=ALUNO${i+1}!$F$167`]);
  while (x.hasNext()) {
      let ss_target = SpreadsheetApp.open(x.next());
      let sh = ss_target.getSheetByName("LISTAFINAL");
      sh.getRange('F5:F15').setValues(formulas);
  }
}
```

Comment: My initial idea was an array system and I have tried some solution, but I didn't know how to write it for this script. Some formulas didn't work, but your has done the job again and vey very fast. Now, one folder with 12 spreadsheet has been processed in only 13 seconds. Thank you very much again.